# arraylist <model> to csv android

Tags: java, android, csv, arraylist, android-volley

i have arraylist with model look like this

```
public class modelriwayat implements Serializable {
private static final long id = 1L;
private String no;
private String waktu;
private String keterangan;


public static long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getNo() {
    return no;
}

public void setNo(String no) {
    this.no = no;
}

public String getWaktu() {
    return waktu;
}

public void setWaktu(String waktu) {
    this.waktu = waktu;
}

public String getKeterangan() {
    return keterangan;
}

public void setKeterangan(String keterangan) {
    this.keterangan = keterangan;
}


}
```

so i define it as ArrayList models = new ArrayList<>();

then i'm using this to put the data(JSON object) which i got using volley

here the code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < riwayat.names().length();i++){
   JSONObject objectriwayat = riwayat.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i+1));
   modelriwayat riwayatmodel = new modelriwayat();

   String nomor = riwayat.names().getString(i);
   String waktu = objectriwayat.getString("waktu");
   String keterangan = objectriwayat.getString("keterangan");
   riwayatmodel.setNo(nomor);
   riwayatmodel.setWaktu(waktu);
   riwayatmodel.setKeterangan(keterangan);
   models.add(riwayatmodel);
 }
```

This data will be implemented to my `listview` with table layout. Now I'm trying to export the data in `models` to csv which I have no idea how
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Must Read this link:

http://www.codejava.net/coding/super-csv-writing-pojos-to-csv-file-using-csvbeanwriter

```
ICsvBeanWriter beanWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter(csvFileName),
    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

String[] header = {"isbn", "title", "author", "publisher", "published", "price"};
beanWriter.writeHeader(header);

for (Book aBook : listBooks) {
    beanWriter.write(aBook, header, processors);
}
```